# Regular expression and newline

Tags: php, regex, newline

I have such text:

> ```
> <Neednt@email.com> If you do so, please include this problem report. 
> <Anotherneednt@email.com> You can delete your
> ```
>
> own
>       text from the attached returned message.
>
> ```
>                    The mail system
>
> <Some@Mail.net>: connect to *.net[82.*.86.*]: Connection timed
> out
> ```

I have to parse email from it. Could you help me with this job?

---

**upd**

There could be another email addresses in **<%here%>**. There should be connection between 'The mail system' text. I need in email which goes after that text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering this text is stored in $text, what about this :

```
$matches = array();
if (preg_match('/<([^>]+)>/', $text, $matches)) {
  var_dump($matches[1]);
}
```

Which gives me :

```
string 'Some@Mail.net' (length=13)
```

Basically, I used a pretty simple regex, that matches :

- a `<` character
- anything that's not a `>` character : `[^>]`

  - at least one time : `[^>]+`
  - capturing it : `([^>]+)`
- a `>` character

So, it captures anything that's between `<` and `>`.

**Edit after comments+edit of the OP :**

If you only want the e-mail address that's after *The mail system*, you could use this :

```
$matches = array();
if (preg_match('/The mail system\s*<([^>]+)>/', $text, $matches)) {
  var_dump($matches[1]);
}
```

In addition to what I posted before, this expects :

- The string `The mail system`
- Any number of white-characters : `\s*`

Comment: There could be another emails in brakes: <mail@mail.com>. There should be connect between, for example, text 'Mail system' and email

Comment: Hu... not quite sure what you want, then... Can you edit your question, to give us a couple of additionnal examples, with the expects outputs ?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `preg_match()` and looking at this input it should be simple:

```
<?php

if (preg_match('/<([^>]*?@[^>]*>/', $data, $matches)) {
  var_dump($matches); // specifically look at $matches[1]
}
```

There are other patterns that would match it, you don't have to stick to that same pattern.  The '<' and '>' in your input are helpful here.